# Countable additivity Riemann integral (Special Case)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, riemann-integration

If $\{O_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ are open intervals in $\mathbb R$ and $\mathscr O = \bigcup \limits_{j=1}^{\infty} O_j$, is it true that

$$\int_{\mathbb R} \chi_{\mathscr O} dx \leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \int_{a_i}^{b_i} \chi_{\mathscr{O}} \, dx?$$

These integrals are Riemann integrals. It is obvious that this is true for lebesgue integral, but I can't see how to show it for Riemann Integrals. (See comments for discussion)

Comment: ah, I forgot about the MCT for riemann integrals, would this work?

Comment: As in, take these sets to be disjoint and let $$\chi_{\mathscr O_n} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \chi_{O_j}$$ and note that this goes montonically p.w. to $\chi_{\mathscr O}$ and that $\chi_{\mathscr{O}}$ is Riemann integrable?